# μTorrent: How do we get the "added" date of a torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

How can we get the actual date/time that a torrent file was added?

In the [μTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) client, only an estimate of *"2 months ago"* is shown:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking specifically about this specific program?

Comment: @Ramhound. Yes, a uTorrent question. Although I'm not sure if the bittorrent protocol will be involved.

Comment: Its not.  When you "open" the torrent a copy is sent to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent` the file creation date is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open: **Preferences** > **Advanced**

and set **gui.use_fuzzy_dates** to **false**

Comment: Btw, why is it called "fuzzy"?

Comment: I don't know, but you can find out more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822124/fuzzy-date-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on any column header in the main body of utorrent and select "Added On" to get the exact date all torrents were added.

Comment: This does not work. As can be seen in the question, it is already selected but they are not giving the exact date. See i.stack.imgur.com/wgJVr.png

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the answer by Encombe, clicking on "**Info**" would also show you the exact "Added On" date for the selected torrent:

[image]

[<kbd>**Enlarge**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEfea.png)